# Is there a common naming convention for variables containing string formats?

Tags: java, string, variables, formatting, naming-conventions

I'm creating a lot of error/warning messages with different variable substitutions.  E.g.

```
ERR_MISSING_FIELD = "Field not found";
ERR_INVALID_VALUE_S = "Invalid value: %s";
ERR_TOO_MANY_OBJECTS_OF_TYPE_DS = "You may not add more than %d %s objects";
```

I'm planning on using the convention shown above - append the substitutions in the variable name.  I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I'd appreciate being pointed to any existing conventions (Java, C#, resource files, anything)

---

**Update** While I'm using variables to store the messages right now, the same question applies when naming resources in .properties or other resource files.

Comment: Move the message inside the `properties` file so that you can change it easity whenever needed and also helps in internationalization.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the places I worked at had a properties file for that.
the key/value of that file looked something like this:

error.missing.field = "Field not found"

error.invalid.value = "Invalid value: %s"

As the comment of James indicated, it also helps in internationalization: 
you simply add the language:

error.missing.field.en = "Field not found" or error.missing.field.fr = "Field not found" (I don't know french, sorry.)

I do not know of any official conventions, but those seem to be the most common practices.

I don't think there is anything different to do in case you have string formats.

Comment: Uh, the correct way to localize strings it to use separate resource bundles. Mangling the property names like this is a good way to mess things up...

Comment: you are right, that's what I meant.
I used the "error.missing.field" in the default properties file.
and in each language file I used something like "error.missing.field.fr".

Comment: What I am objecting to is the `.fr` suffix for property names. It means that apart from loading the correct resource bundle, you also have to repeatedly write messy boilerplate code such as `getString("buttons.cancel" + localeSuffix)`, instead of just `getString("buttons.cancel")`.

Comment: but what if your server sends messages to different clients?
each client has its own locale, so you need to be able to use all locales while still distinguishing between them.
the files are separated mainly for easier maintenance.